# how to create range column based on a column value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have sample data in table which contains `distance_travelled_in_meter`, where the values are of Integer type as follows:

```
distance_travelled_in_meter | 
--------------------------- |
                        500 | 
                        1221|
                        990 |
                         575|
```

I want to create range based on the value of the column `distance_travelled_in_meter`. Range column has values with `500` intervals.
The result dataset is as follows:

```
distance_travelled_in_meter | range
--------------------------- |---------
                        500 | 1-500
                        1221|1000-1500
                        990 |500-1000
                         575|500-1000
```

For value `500`, the range is `1-500` as it is within 500 meter, `1221` is in `1000-1500` and so on..

I tried using `Spark.sql.functions.sequence` but it takes the start and stop column values which is not what I want and want to be in range that I mentioned above. And also it creates an Range array from start column value to stop column value.

I'm using Spark2.4.2 with Scala 2.11.12
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain multiple `when` expressions that you generate dynamically using something like this:

```
val maxDistance = 1221 // you can get this from the dataframe

val ranges = (0 until maxDistance by 500).map(x => (x, x + 500))

val rangeExpr = ranges.foldLeft(lit(null)) {
  case (acc, (lowerBound, upperBound)) =>
    when(
      col("distance_travelled_in_meter").between(lowerBound, upperBound),
      lit(s"$lowerBound-$upperBound")
    ).otherwise(acc)
}

val df1 = df.withColumn("range", rangeExpr)
```